# Printing from Matlab to Excel

Tags: matlab

I am creating a dummy example for my situation. Real problem is way more complicated.

Dummy Example:

I have a struct of size 2 with an entry called 'name' and an array of size 2x1.

So, the Struct called Store looks like:

```
Store(1).name = 'Apple';
Store(1).Data = [1; 2];

Store(2).name = 'Orange';
Store(2).Data = [24; 57];
```

I want to print this to excel such that it looks like the following:

```
Apple     1
Apple     2
Orange    24
Orange    57
```

I don't even know how to start with the above example. I have used xlswrite in the past but never for mixed type data.

Comment: Could you just print it into a csv and then manually open it in excel? I'm not familiar enough with matlab to know how to do that, but I'm sure it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all your `Data` fields are of size `2x1`, you should be able to the following:

```
% prepare cell to hold your data
xlData = cell(2*numel(store), 2);
% fill column 1:
xlData(1:2:end-1,1) = {store.name};
xlData(2:2:end,1) = xlData(1:2:end-1);
% fill column 2:
xlData(:,2) = num2cell(vertcat(store.Data));
% write to excel:
xlswrite('yourExcelfile.xlsx', xlData)
```

Got no Matlab at hand to test, but it should help you get going.

Since `xlswrite` takes a cell-array, there's no issue with mixed datatypes.

Comment: Thanks very elegant solution.